# Problem in understanding equations of circle and the intercepts made by it on the axes.

Tags: geometry

Everyone knows the general eqn. of a circle is $$(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = a^2$$ having centre at $(h,k)$ and radius $a$ . When this circle touches the axis of x, the eqn. becomes $$(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = k^2$$ . Its intersection with the x-axis  ie . $y = 0$ is $h$ . But my book says

> By putting $y = 0$ in the eqn. we get $$ (x - h)^2 = 0$$ ie. it gives two equal values of x as x-axis is a tangent.

Now, what does this mean giving two equal values of x?? What does it want to tell?? There is only one point which the circle touches ie. $(h,0)$ . So, why does it say about intersection and two points??? The circle has not intersected the axis. So, why does the book say so??

Next, the lengths of the intercepts on the axes made by the circle is $2 . \sqrt{g^2 - c}$ and $2 . \sqrt{f^2 - c}$ . Ok. But then the book writes

> In case the circle tnuches the axis of x at $(x_1 , 0)$, then it will intersect the x-axis at **two coincident points**. Thus $$ x^2 + 2gx + c = (x - x_1)^2$$ . And so is in the case of y-axis.

First, it says the circle touches the axis. Then it says the circle intersects the axis at **two coincident points** and then writes an equation from nowhere. What is going on??? If the circle really touches, then why should it intersect??? And how does this equation arise???

Please help. I am really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue circle cuts x-axis, the secant, at two points.These cutting points are two distinctly different roots.

The red circle cuts x-axis at two coinciding points. It is a tangent now, not a secant.Both roots have equal value. In fact, that is the definition of tangency.

The words tangent, secant are not to be confused with trigonometric function names!

[image: TANGENT AND SECANT ROOTS]

Answer (score 0):

number 1:

it is somehow like the set of solutions for an equation of second degree:

1- $0$ solutions: No intersection between line and circle

2- $2$ distinct solutions: The line intersects twice with the circle

3- $2$ identical solutions: The line is tangent to the circle (touching it as your book says)

[image]